# Getting element from flat jquery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

got something like:

```
var asd = $('<div id="0"/><div id="1"/><div id="2"/>');
```

I want to get the div with id = 1. .find is not working. How do I get the element to change some values or to append stuff to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()`:

```
var asd = $('<div id="0"/><div id="1"/><div id="2"/>');
var div1 = asd.filter("#1");
```

The `.find()` method is for looking *inside* a container object, and your list of `<div>` elements has no outer container.

Comment: Oh, didn't try filter. Thanks a lot. Forgot jquery representates objects as arrays too. It is a bit diffcult to google the right way to do it, so I asked. And as always some trolls feel the need to downvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

use `filter`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var asd = $('<div id="div0"/><div id="div1"/><div id="div2"/>');
  $('body').append(asd.filter('[id="div2"]'));
});
```

```css
#div2{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```